# What is the fastest notification possible? Does it depend on the provider (telegram/slack/email etc)?

Tags: node.js, automation, push-notification, notifications

For example, I want information about a new tweet from my code. How can I get the information as quickly as possible after the trigger?

For example, I can use telegram but I have a 3 second delay. How about discord, slack, or maybe the easiest way is via email? Do you have any thoughts on what to use to make it the fastest of all possible options?

I tried using telegram, but it's too slow, maybe I don't know how to do it right?

Comment: Your question is too broad, it depends from many factors. Latency, server load, your code..

Comment: I am well aware that many things depend on me, such as ping, the right code or a good server. But the question is very legitimate, because every solution works differently and not everything depends on me, I ask what will be the most practical without fumbling and looking in the dark